# Xcode 4 compiler doesn't see my instance variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

So I'm working on iPhone and everything is going swell. Except for the last two hours. I was editing some class, then saved and built and suddenly I had tons of errors in another class implementation file. It seems that all the errors have to do with class members (variables) because the only errors I have are "object undeclared", those objects being the class members. Syntax is ok and all, so I believe it isn't anything like that. Did anyone have this problem before?

Example:

```
Foo.h

@interface Foo : NSObject
{
@private
    int m_1;
    NSString *m_2;
    NSDictionary *m_3;
}

-(id) init;
-(void) dealloc;
-(int) bar;
-(int) barWithFoo:(Foo *)foo;

@end

Foo.m

#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo

-(id) init
{
    return self = [super init]; 
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    // code
}

-(int) bar
{
    if (m_1 > MAX_DECL) /* error here, m_1 undeclared */
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    NSLog(m_2); /* error here, m_2 undeclared */
}

// etc...

@end
```

Comment: Could you have another `Foo.h` somewhere in the search path?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem with the code you wrote for your question? If not, we'll need to see the actual code that produces the errors.

Comment: Also, note that Xcode 4 is under NDA, so we can't talk about it here. If something doesn't work in it, try it in Xcode 3, and if that works, you should file a bug about 4. https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 1):

A bit unspecific question, it's hard to help with this info available... However, I'd check #import declarations to make sure all files are included. Also, make sure you haven't renamed a class (it can be a typo) and both declaration in .h and definition in .m have the same name.

Comment: Yes I have checked all #import declarations and the name is correct. Also the files are in the correct folder and I am editing the correct files. I can't really post my whole class implementation file, but basically it's as I have described, btw I have edited the OP.

Comment: I guess you have tried full rebuild, haven't you? Erase all temporary files manually.

Comment: Yup, I've cleaned all targets and rebuilt several times.

Comment: Try to localize the issue. Remove the "problem" class from the project (replace it with a blank) and check whether the project will compile. If yes - insert the problem class into the new empty project and check it step-by-step.

Comment: This will sound stupid, but I just backup the contents of the files, erased them, saved them, then reverted them to the backup I made and now it works! WTF? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Ricardo Ferreira: Most likely, you had a non-visible non-breaking space or another special character in the file.